# What does the //= assignment operator do in Python

Tags: python, assignment-operator

I was reading http://hyperpolyglot.org/scripting and stumbled into the //= assignemnt operator. I've never seen it before. What does it do?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

Comment: Googling for `python operators` and doing ctrl-F and searching for `//=` will result in `ifloordiv`, from which one can assume that `//` is equivalent to `/` followed by `math.floor`, but faster (like C does integer division).

Comment: Stackoverflow was faster than my google search. Nice.

Comment: Mitch Hedberg explains it better than I can: "I had a velco wallet in a casino. That sound annoyed the hell out of me. Whenever I lost money, and I opened the wallet, it was like the sound of my addiction."

Answer (score 9):

If `x /= y` means `x = x / y`, then I'd assume `x //= y` means `x = x // y`.

`//` is integer division

Answer (score 6):

It does in-place [integer division](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations).

For what it's worth, it's also available in the `operator` module, as [`operator.ifloordiv`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.ifloordiv).

Answer (score 1):

For the code

```
x = 16
x //= 2
```

The value of `x` is 8. Basically, `x = x // 2`, integer division